# How to access my state of array in another router page VUEJS, VUEX

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js, vue-router

I made a page with two routes one is the home page another is the config where you can decide what should be written to that container, now in the config panel I was able to get the input values, I put them to my state with map actions now I am getting an array with string values in it.

How can I access that array with mapGetters ?   I link my code:

```html
<template>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 v-show="elementVisible" class="info">{{ message }}</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</template>

<script>
  import moment from "moment";
  import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

  export default {
    name: "Home",
    data() {
      return {
        // message: this.store.state.message
        elementVisible: true
      };
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters(["message", "sec"]),

      ...mapGetters({
        message: "message",
        sec: "sec"
      }),
      createdDate() {
        return moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY ");
      },
      createdHours() {
        return moment().format("HH:mm ");
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.$store.dispatch("SET_MESSAGE");
      this.$store.dispatch("SET_SEC");

      setTimeout(() => (this.elementVisible = false), this.sec);
    }
  };
</script>
```

so what I have to do is to put to that{{message}}   template my message which I received from the config panel and which is in my state right now sitting there as an array of string, for example, ["hello", "how are you"] that's how they are sitting there, so how can I grab the first one('hello')   and write it out as a clean string and not as ["hello"] if you know how to grab all of them would be even better.

(RightNow it's just putting that whole array to my template)

Maybe I should something rewrite in my storejs file?
STOREJS:

```js
const state = {
  message: [],
  // console.log(message);
  sec: +[]
  // other state
};
const getters = {
  message: state => {
    // console.log(this.state.message);

    return state.message;
  },

  sec: state => {
    return state.sec;
  }
  // other getters
};

const actions = {
  setMessage: ({ commit, state }, inputs) => {
    commit(
      "SET_MESSAGE",
      inputs.map(input => input.message)
    );

    return state.message;
  },

  setSec: ({ commit, state }, inputs) => {
    commit("SET_TIMEOUT", inputs.map(x => x.sec).map(Number));
    console.log(inputs.map(x => x.sec).map(Number));
    return state.sec;
  }
  // other actions
};
const mutations = {
  SET_MESSAGE: (state, newValue) => {
    state.message = newValue;
  },

  SET_TIMEOUT: (state, newSecVal) => {
    state.sec = newSecVal;
  }
  // other mutations
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
};
```

what my homepage should do is that it writes out that message and there is a sec value which stands for the timeout, after that I want to continue with the second value in that array and when that times out I should want the third to be written out.. and so on.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Your `message` Array is being mapped correctly with `mapGetters`, but you're flattening it as a String when you put it inside the template with `{{message}}`, since the template interpolation logic covert objects to strings, the same as calling `Array.toString` in this case. You need to iterate it, i.e. using the `v-for` directive:

```
<template>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 v-show="elementVisible" class="info">
        <span v-for="m of message" :key="m">{{m}}</span>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</template>
```

Of course, if you only need the first item, you could show it directly using:

```
<template>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 v-show="elementVisible" class="info">{{message[0] || 'No message'}}</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</template>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer it helps but  it just writes out both at the same time but what i want to do is that im giving in my config panel a message and a  sec which stands for timeout, so what i want to do is to write out the first element  and be in the screen till its time is over(which is given as i said) and after that it should continue to write to the screen the second element of the array (and also waits till the time for its is over) and continues so on . Can you help me with that please? Thank you. (im making a table similar what you see in citys which displays some infos )

Comment: I don't think your desires are explained well enough in the question. I suggest to edit the question or even create a new question with more information. And, of course, the first thing I need to understand is: why Vuex?

Comment: i mean why not?

Comment: From the [Vuex docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/#when-should-i-use-it): _"Vuex helps us deal with shared state management with the cost of more concepts and boilerplate. It's a trade-off between short term and long term productivity (...) But if you are building a medium-to-large-scale SPA, chances are you have run into situations that make you think about how to better handle state outside of your Vue components, and Vuex will be the natural next step for you."_. I don't know your project at all, but the needs you have shown doesn't seen to be so much to justify Vuex usage.

Comment: yes thats right, however i made another topic with my real problem would you please look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62717074/putting-things-to-display-from-an-array-with-the-help-of-mapgetters-vuejs-vue